# postgresql revoke access to login role

Tags: postgresql

I executed this query that gave schema access to a login role called test

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA open_waters TO test;
```

I want to now revoke the access to test

Answer (score 1):

In general, a GRANT is revoked with its opposite command having `REVOKE` instead of `GRANT` and `FROM` instead of `TO`:

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA open_waters FROM test;
```